# can't run apple watch app on device - "failed to attach to process ID ..."

Tags: xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

I can't run my app on the Apple Watch; whenever I try to run it I only see the loading indicator in my app on the device, in the console I see

```
error: failed to attach to process ID ...
```

when I set a breakpoint right at the beginning of the app it sometimes works - what am I missing here?

Comment: From the Xcode "Product" menu, choose "Stop", then "Clean". Then build it again. It can take quite a long time for it to attach to the process (in my experience, up to 30 seconds). Also, try launching your app on the watch from the watch simulator home screen - I have found that this can also get it to attach more reliably.

Comment: starting the app from the simulator home screen? I want to run it on the device...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said from either the actual watch or the watch simulator. I've had it where it hasn't connected to the process first time, but when I've then launched the app by tapping it's icon, I get the "Running...", then "Attaching...." messages more consistently from Xcode.

Comment: You might want to try reboots of both your iPhone and Apple Watch, and retry.

Comment: but do I have to run the iPhone app or the Watchkit App?